# How to serve utility data in Odata?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I want to have a UtilityController with some utility methods to serve data in Odata Api in Microsoft Asp.NET.
Currently if I want implement a controller its based on some entity like for `Product` I will have a `ProductController` with EDMModelBuit as

```
  builder.EntitySet<Product>("Product");
```

with other types if they are in `Product` type e.g.

```
  builder.EntitySet<ProductGroup>("ProductGroup");
```

Now what is the solution If I want to have a controller like `UtilityController` with methods as `GetAnyList`, `GetOfferTypes` and `PutNewEnumTypeInOfferBase` and I do not have any Utility type etc, its just a utility data related to any entity or may be not. e.g

```
 public class UtilityController : ODataController
{
    private DbContext db = new DbContext();

    public List<string> getOfferBase()
    {
        return UtilityService.GetOfferBase();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

then I can get this utility data as

```
 http://localhost:47120/odata/Utility/getOfferBase
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbound function/action match your requirement. Applying them, you can send such requests but do not need an entity set:

```
1. GET http://host/odata/getOfferBase
2. POST http://host/odata/PutNewEnumTypeInOfferBase
```

To add an unbound function/action you need to do this:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.Function

ActionConfiguration PutNewEnumTypeInOfferBase = modelBuilder.Action("PutNewEnumTypeInOfferBase");
PutNewEnumTypeInOfferBase .Parameter<string>("Title");
PutNewEnumTypeInOfferBase .ReturnsFromEntitySet<Movie>("Movies");

builder.Function("GetSalesTaxRate")
            .Returns<double>()
            .Parameter<string>("state");
```

For more, please refer:
https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/
https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataActionsSample/